# Azure DevOps language of git repository?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I saw on github.com we can see the language used for each repository. Something similar exist for the projects section of Azure DevOps but I could not find anything more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, if you are talking about something like this in GitHub repo:

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no such corresponding thing in Azure DevOps repo.

You could submit a feature request in our [Develop 
 Community  site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion. Sorry for any inconvenience.

[image]